# Remove an object from a picture through the use of lower resolution pictures without that object

Tags: software-recommendation

I have multiple pictures of different resolutions.

Three of those pictures are without an object and exactly like I want them, but they are really small (2x smaller than wanted at minimum), and I have a good-looking big picture, but with an object blocking about 20% of it.

Is there a way, software, website or etc. to remove the object from my big picture, filling in with "logical" pieces from the smaller images?

The goal here is to have an image without that object and the best possible resolution in the end.

My first idea was that maybe there's an AI tool that can intelligently find common parts in images and "fix" another image with them.

BTW. The unwanted object is fully opaque and it's not a watermark.

Answer (score 2):

If the high resolution version without the unwanted object is unavailable you can try to manually copy the missing content from a low resolution version to a new layer and adjust its color and contrast. Before copying try to enlarge the low resolution version to the same resolution as the high resolution image. If you do it with a clever image enlargener (On1 Resize, Smilla Enlargener, "preserve details resampling" in a modern version of Photoshop or others) you can get thin lines and sharp borders still as thin and sharp.

Unfortunately nothing automatic can guess right those details which are fully non-existent in the low resolution version.  BTW. Smilla Enlargener is freeware.